# Stylesheet for everything

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to load the CSS file for everything.
For elements: tabs, sidebars, tags , windows, options, developer tools, etc.
I need this to change the scroll bars.

How to do it in Firefox addons-sdk?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: This is an ok question. I totally understand it. Please remove the down votes fellows.

Answer (score 1):

By evrything you actually mean the browser area. So what you want to do is write CSS within the brackets of `@-moz-document url("chrome://browser/content/browser.xul") {` and `}`. Otherwise the CSS will affect things within webpages.

There are two ways to load in a CSS sheet, one is with the `nsIStyleSheetService` and one is with 
`window.loadSheet`.

The `window.loadSheet` is the recommended way. You would do it something like this:

```
function registerWindows() {
    var _uri = Services.io.newURI("chrome://aus-view/skin/toolbar.css", null, null);
    aWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindowUtils).loadSheet(_uri, 1);
}


function unregisterWindows() {
    var _uri = Services.io.newURI("chrome://aus-view/skin/toolbar.css", null, null);
    aWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindowUtils).removeSheet(_uri, 1);
}
```

You would have to make sure to load your sheet into newly opened windows.

With the nsIStyleSheetService, you just `loadAndRegisterSheet` and then you don't have to worry about window opening and closing. But it's harder on performance I heard. I don't know the source on this performance though.

```
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
var sss = Cc['@mozilla.org/content/style-sheet-service;1'].getService(Ci.nsIStyleSheetService);
var cssUri = Services.io.newURI('chrome://content/path/to/your/file.css', null, null);
sss.loadAndRegisterSheet(cssUri, sss.USER_SHEET);
```

Then when you want to remove it you just do:

```
sss.unregisterSheet(cssUri, sss.USER_SHEET);
```

Now those both used files. You can make a URI without any files like this:

```
var css = '';
css += '* { background-color: red; }';
css += '*.hover { background-color: blue; }';
var cssEncoded = encodeURIComponent(css);
var cssEncodedWithDataURL = 'data:text/css,' + cssEncoded
```

Then we just make our URI the same way: `var cssUri = Services.io.newURI(cssEncodedWithDataURL, null, null);` Then you just load the stylehseet the same way. (Example using 2nd method: `sss.unregisterSheet(cssUri, sss.USER_SHEET)`)

Comment: I can not use the addons-sdk. Each time the same thing ...; |

Comment: You mean you can't use the above code in the sdk? you hvae to put at the top: `const {Cc, Ci, Cu} = require("chrome");` and to make the `cssUri` do `var cssUri = Services.io.newURI(self.data('yourFileName.css'), null, null);` I didn't type this stuff out above because I always have to look up the sdk stuff so i was lazy.

Comment: I started the supplement, but:
Style only works for the sidebar, Libraries window.
The rest does not see the style.
I would like to work:
on all pages (tabs), panels, panel tool developer of Firefox, Firebug panel, etc.
Each scroll bar has to have changed style.

Comment: Try removing the `@-moz-document url` wrap.

Comment: I found a solution.
I had to change `sss.USER_SHEET` on `sss.AGENT_SHEET`
`sss.loadAndRegisterSheet (cssUri, sss.AGENT_SHEET);`

Comment: Ah thanks I never knew about that one. Big +1 there.