# How to write a firefox plugin that automatically changes page layout?

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-addon

I was wondering if you can give me any pointers on how to write a firefox plugin/add-on, that would change the layout of the page one is on, based on a pre- written CSS file.

It's meant as a prototype and what I want to be able to do initially is to make my browser automatically change the background color of certain div's, when I navigate to the chosen page. I'm only trying to make it work for a couple of sites.

I speak python, javascript/jquery, css, html ..

Comment: You can apply a style sheet like to the browser context or to webpages: [StackOverflow - firefox-addon :: Stylesheet for everything](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24495817/1828637)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to accomplish your goal using the [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/stylish/?src=userprofile) addon without writing your own. This basically allow you to attach custom CSS overrides based on a URL pattern.

If you want to do this and write your own extension, you could use the addon-sdk and make use of [page-mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod). Here is [a tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Modifying_Web_Pages_Based_on_URL) that will help you with running the script only on the URL's you specify. [As of FireFox 34](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#Attaching_stylesheets) you should be able to attach actual CSS files instead of having to rely on JavaScript. Learning the addon-sdk it a lot less intimidating than making an old style / low-level extension and should be sufficient for your needs.

There are a few different ways to accomplish similar things, so you will need to experiment based on your needs.